# In mu4e, how do you open a message in a web browser?

Tags: mu4e, web-browser

I'm using the mu4e layer in spacemacs on develop. When I press `a` (for action) and then `V`, it opens an email in Firefox. But I want it to open in a browser of my choosing (qutebrowser). The manual says, somewhat cryptically: `Now, when viewing such a difficult message, type aV, and the message opens inside a webbrowser. You can influence the browser with browse-url-generic-program`

I don't know what it means by "influence," but I tried this:

`(setq browse-url-generic-program "qutebrowser")`

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of the variable `browse-url-browser-function`
I can't test with qutebrowser, but the following works with conkeror

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic)
(setq browse-url-generic-program "conkeror")
```

After setting this variables mu4e opens messages in conkeror. Before it was firefox.